# Always show the file path in FilteredResourcesSelectionDialog

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

In the `FilteredResourcesSelectionDialog`, some items show the file path beside them in grey color while others don"t show the path.

Why does this happen and how do I make sure that the file paths are always shown?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The path is shown when there are multiple entries with the same name. This is to allow you to distinguish the entries.

If you create a class derived from `FilteredResourcesSelectionDialog` (or anything based on `FilteredItemsSelectionDialog`) you can override the `isDuplicateElement` method to control this, for example:

```
@Override
public boolean isDuplicateElement(Object item)
{
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Make sense, is it possible to make them always appear?
Otherwise a user may find it confusing.

Comment: Added isDuplicateElement method

Comment: Perfect ! You are a real hero :)